# + symbol missing while passing values using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to pass two values from a page to another page using javaScript as follows:

```
window.location.href = "changefile.php?equation="+s+"&constant="+c;
```

Inside `changefile.php` I am getting the values as

```
$eqn =$_GET['equation'];
$cons=$_GET['constant'];
```

It is working fine for all the cases except:

Suppose the value of equation is **x+1**.

I am passing it using `window.location.href = "changefile.php?equation="+s+"&constant="+c;`

I am getting as **x 1** as output. The **+** is missing.

Please help me. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to encode `s` and `c` parameters.

> The `encodeURIComponent()` method encodes a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) component by replacing each instance of certain characters by one, two, three, or four escape sequences representing the UTF-8 encoding of the character (will only be four escape sequences for characters composed of two "surrogate" characters).

```
window.location.href = "changefile.php?equation="+encodeURIComponent(s)+"&constant="+encodeURIComponent(c);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode the parameter value using [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

```
window.location.href = "changefile.php?equation=" + encodeURIComponent(s) + "&constant=" + encodeURIComponent(c);
```